# Directory searching in PHP with multiple criteria

Tags: php, search, directory, glob

I've been trying to find a way to search a directory with multiple criteria in PHP with little luck.

I have a folder that contains multiple versions of the same file but in different languages and for different devices:

e.g.

```
 1. file_en_v980.jar

 2. file_fr_v980.jar

 3. file_en_v990.jar

 4. file_fr_v990.jar
```

I want to be able to search the directory for all English (en) .jar files for the v980.

I've tried this:

```
foreach(glob('./'.$installer_location.'/'.$brand_name.'/*en*.jar') as $filename){
    echo $filename."</br>";
}
```

It works, but returns the french (fr) file too.

I've tried this:

```
foreach(glob('./'.$installer_location.'/'.$brand_name.'/*en,v980*.jar') as $filename){
    echo $filename."</br>";
}
```

But it returns nothing so I'm assuming I've got the syntax wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Addition:

Based on the suggestion from the comment below I tried this:

```
foreach(glob('./'.$installer_location.'/'.$brand_name.'/*{en,v980}*.jar',GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
    echo $filename."</br>";
}
```

This returned all the files that had either en, v980 or both. I just need to figure out if there is a way to say must contain both.

Comment: Why `en,v980` instead of `en_v980`?

Comment: I thought that the ',' would separate the criteria where 'en_v980' would search for a matching string. The actual files names are much bigger than the ones I've used in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's glob() essentially uses the same wildcarding/matching engine as a unix shell. With your version, you're searching for files that contain `en,v980`, and it's not being treated as "alternation". http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

Try

```
glob('..../*{en,v980}*.jar')
```

instead (note the `{}`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried it and it doesn't work. I did something very similar before posting the question as it was written in the documentation for GLOB, it used GLOB_BRACE before the closing parentheses. It's strange that it doesn't work as the documentation example is actually what I need.